# required_if validation rule with the array validation rule is not working | Laravel | Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have the following validation rule in which I need to sure that the `streaming_platforms` array includes the correct information. So the `stream_key` and `stream_url` are required if the `enable` key is true. The `stream_key` should be a string and `stream_url` should be a URL.

```
$validator = Validator::make($input, [
    'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
    'type' => 'required|in:private,public',
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_url' => 'required_if:streaming_platforms.*.enable,true|url',
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_key' => 'required_if:streaming_platforms.*.enable,true|string',
], [
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_url.required_if' => 'The stream url field is required when platform is enable.',
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_key.required_if' => 'The stream key field is required when platform is enable.',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return $this->failResponse([
        "message" => $validator->errors()->first(),
        "messages" => $validator->errors(),
    ], 422);
}
```

Everything is working fine, but the URL and string validation rule for stream_url and stream_key respective is fire even though the `enable` value is false. So why does not just stop checking the next rules if the `required_if` is not applied?

So I tried with the following data.

```
{
    "name":"testing",
    "type":"public",
    "streaming_platforms":[
        {"id":16,"platform":"youtube","enable":true,"stream_url":"https://www.google.com","stream_key":"abdefghijk"},
        {"id":17,"platform":"facebook","enable":false,"stream_url":null,"stream_key":null},
        {"id":18,"platform":"custom","enable":false,"stream_url":null,"stream_key":null}
    ]
}
```

So it returns

> The streaming_platforms.1.stream_url format is invalid. for the
> Facebook row.

I read somewhere that you can do something like the following i.e by using the `sometimes` rule. but I don't how can I do with the array type data.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    'is_public_template' => 'boolean',

    'logo' => ['required_if:is_public_template,true'],
]);
$validator->sometimes('logo', 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,jpg|dimensions:min_width=128,min_height=128', function ($input) {
    return $input->is_public_template;
});
```

Real use case in form of an image. [image: multiple stream selection.]

Comment: you need to add additional nullable/sometimes because the required rule is somehow set by default even if other conditions do not meet. Another example of this is `numeric` rule which is applied even if the value is null, so to make it work only when that value is present, you need to add nullable rule also

Comment: `nullable` is not working even though.

Comment: I expect the problem is your rule `required_if:streaming_platforms.*.enable,true` that * means a wildcard, so if *any* of the elements have enable:true then that rule will be triggered.

Comment: no miken it is for array element. check this link. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `exclude_if` rule to [conditionally exclude](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) the field from validation.

```php
$data = [
    "name" => "testing",
    "type" => "public",
    "streaming_platforms" => [
        ["id" => 16, "platform" => "youtube", "enable" => true, "stream_url" => "https://www.google.com", "stream_key" => "abdefghijk"],
        ["id" => 17, "platform" => "facebook", "enable" => false, "stream_url" => null, "stream_key" => null],
        ["id" => 18, "platform" => "custom", "enable" => false, "stream_url" => null, "stream_key" => null],
     ]
];

$rules = [
    'name' => 'required|string|min:3|max:255',
    'type' => 'required|in:private,public',
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_url' => 'exclude_if:streaming_platforms.*.enable,false|required|url',
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_key' => 'exclude_if:streaming_platforms.*.enable,false|required|string',
];

$messages = [
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_url.required' => 'The stream url field is required when platform is enable.',
    'streaming_platforms.*.stream_key.required' => 'The stream key field is required when platform is enable.',
];

$v = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);

dump($v->fails());

// false
```

Note this also prevents the data from being output with the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validated()` method:

```php
dump($v->validated());
```

Output:

```
   [
     "name" => "testing",
     "type" => "public",
     "streaming_platforms" => [
       [
         "stream_url" => "https://www.google.com",
         "stream_key" => "abdefghijk",
       ],
     ],
   ]
```

Comment: Can you verify why this error message is not coming in any case "The stream url field is required when platform is enable."?

Comment: So validation error message stack should be like checking if the enable is true then fields are required (in case any one is empty(stream_url or stream_key)) and if I enter something in the URL then it should check the format.

Comment: Why would it? You have only enable:true on one item, and it has the URL set.

Comment: This is the sample data. please check my updated question. A user can either check or uncheck the streaming platform and then he has to enter both the key and URL

Comment: All stream platforms are optional. If the user checks either one of them then he has to enter both URL and key with required and format validation.

Comment: Oh I see; it's failing on the `url` rule; if you change the messages it should work as expected. I updated the `$messages` array in the answer.

Comment: Yes. I already did(and see) that. that is why I delete my comment and upvote your answer. Thank buddy. just replace required_if to required.